# Data are overwrite how to solve that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, selenium, for-loop

With every iteration through the loop, the previously extracted data is overwritten. How can I solve this problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd


# url='https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00M0DWQYI?th=1'
# url='https://www.amazon.com/dp/B010RWD4GM?th=1'
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
df_urls = pd.read_csv('D:/selenium/inputs/amazone-asin.csv',encoding='utf-8')
list_dicts_urls =df_urls.to_dict('records')

item=dict()
product=[]
for url in list_dicts_urls:
    
    product_url = 'https://' + url['MARKETPLACE'] + '/dp/' + url['ASIN']
    driver.get(product_url)


    try:
        item['title'] = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span#productTitle').text
    except:
        item['title'] = ''
        
    try:
        item['brand'] = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a#bylineInfo').text.replace('Visit the','').replace('Store','').strip()
    except:
        item['brand'] = ''
    try:
        rating = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span#acrCustomerReviewText').text.replace('ratings','').strip()
        rating = int(rating.replace(',', ''))
        item['rating'] = rating
    except:
        item['rating'] = ''
        
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        p1=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="a-price-whole"]').text
        p2= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="a-price-fraction"]').text
        item['price']=p1+p2
    except:
        item['price']=''
        
    product.append(item)
    
df=pd.DataFrame(product)
df.to_csv("ama.csv")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define `item=dict()` inside the `for` loop. Otherwise this is the same, single `item` object used in all the loop iterations.
Try this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd


# url='https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00M0DWQYI?th=1'
# url='https://www.amazon.com/dp/B010RWD4GM?th=1'
PATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver =webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
df_urls = pd.read_csv('D:/selenium/inputs/amazone-asin.csv',encoding='utf-8')
list_dicts_urls =df_urls.to_dict('records')

product=[]
for url in list_dicts_urls:

    item=dict()
    
    product_url = 'https://' + url['MARKETPLACE'] + '/dp/' + url['ASIN']
    driver.get(product_url)


    try:
        item['title'] = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span#productTitle').text
    except:
        item['title'] = ''
        
    try:
        item['brand'] = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'a#bylineInfo').text.replace('Visit the','').replace('Store','').strip()
    except:
        item['brand'] = ''
    try:
        rating = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'span#acrCustomerReviewText').text.replace('ratings','').strip()
        rating = int(rating.replace(',', ''))
        item['rating'] = rating
    except:
        item['rating'] = ''
        
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        p1=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="a-price-whole"]').text
        p2= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[@class="a-price-fraction"]').text
        item['price']=p1+p2
    except:
        item['price']=''
        
    product.append(item)
    
df=pd.DataFrame(product)
df.to_csv("ama.csv")
```